# Ajax send array of data to backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have table where I loop dynamic data and each of those dynamic items has input fields then I send those input fields along with dynamic items id to back-end.

#### Issue

Issue is that my fields in ajax giving me strange data as array.

#### Code

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
  $('.newservicesSave').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var idmess = $(this).data("id");


    // this array data are wrong
    var newservices = [];
    $(".newservices").each(function() {
      newservices.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log('newservices: ', newservices);

    $.ajax({
      url: '{{ url('
      panel / addnewservices ') }}/' + encodeURI(idmess),
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        "id": idmess,
        "newservices": newservices,
        "_method": 'POST',
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#servicesTable').empty();
        $.each(data.data, function(key, value) {
          $("#servicesTable").append('<tr><td>' + value['name'] + '</td><td><textarea name="' + services['key']['description'] + '" class="form-control" name="description"></textarea><input type="hidden" name="' + services['key']['service_id'] + '"/></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Harga" name="' + services['key']['price'] + '"/></td><td><input class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="' + services['key']['active'] + '" /></td></tr>');
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Service</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Harga</th>
      <th>Active</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($services as $index => $service)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$service->name}}</td>
      <td>
        <textarea name="newservices[{{$index}}][description]" class="newservices form-control" name="description"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" class="newservices" name="newservices[{{$index}}][service_id]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="newservices form-control" placeholder="Harga" name="newservices[{{$index}}][price]" />
      </td>
      <td><input class="newservices form-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="newservices[{{$index}}][active]" /></td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" data-id="{{$laundry->id}}" class="newservicesSave btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

#### Result

[image: one]

**Expected data from ajax**

Data should come to backend as follow structure

```
newservices [
    0 [
        active => 0,
        service_id => '123456',
        description => 'abc',
        price => '1000'
    ],
    1 [...],
    2 [...],
    // etc.
]
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: `"newservices": newservices` might need to be `"newservices": JSON.stringify(newservices)` .... since `dataType: "JSON"` only applies to the return type.

Comment: @GetSet yes it gives better result `["werwef","","2","on","ewef2","","23","on","","","","on","","","","on"]` yet is not divided like my expected sample code.

Comment: Backend code must parse that into valid object/array from json. You dont mention your backend language tho for me to further comment.

Comment: @GetSet my backend is laravel (php) why i say in that structure? cause later I can loop them like `foreach($request->input('newservices') as $service) {..}`

Comment: Ok on php, you could attempt a `json_decode()` on that received by backend

Comment: @GetSet I don't think so as i said it has to send array in array. `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

Comment: @GetSet this is what I get in backend now `array:16 [
  0 => "werwef"
  1 => null
  2 => "2"
  3 => "on"
  4 => "ewef2"
  5 => null
  6 => "23"
  7 => "on"
  8 => null
  9 => null
  10 => null
  11 => "on"
  12 => null
  13 => null
  14 => null
  15 => "on"
]`

Comment: Any way to get "laravel" not to assume you want to decode your json automatically? I see its losing your key names. If no way to configure or lot's of research, I'd just send it as a "hex" string and json_decode manually.

Comment: @GetSet if I send them as `[ 0 [active => 0,service_id => '123456',description => 'abc',price => '1000'], ...]` then there is no need to decode at all I just simply loop them the problem is right now as you said it does not have key names `0, 1, 2, ...`

Comment: jQuery will properly form encode an array, no need to stringify or use json_decode(). What is needed is creating the proper structure needed to start with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the structure you want you will need to loop over rows and create an object for each row

Try something like :

```
var newservices = $('#myTable tbody tr').map(function(){
    var $row = $(this);
    return {
        description: $row.find('.newservices[name*="description"]').val(),
        service_id : $row.find('.newservices[name*="service_id"]').val(),
        // ... same for other properties
    }    
}).get();
```

Comment: `edit:647 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'` from `find(.newservices[name*="description")`

Comment: Ooops...I left out outer selector quotes. See update

Comment: What only gets one row? The js array or php?

Comment: I removed it cause I understood my mistake, please wait I'm testing it :)